# Project Euler Problem 26 Python String Limits in Fraction Numbers

Tags: python

[Project Euler Problem 26:](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26)

A unit fraction contains 1 in the numerator. The decimal representation of the unit fractions with denominators 2 to 10 are given:

1/2 =   0.5

1/3 =   0.(3)

1/4 =   0.25

1/5 =   0.2

1/6 =   0.1(6)

1/7 =   0.(142857)

1/8 =   0.125

1/9 =   0.(1)

1/10    =   0.1

Where 0.1(6) means 0.166666..., and has a 1-digit recurring cycle. It can be seen that 1/7 has a 6-digit recurring cycle.
Find the value of d < 1000 for which 1/d contains the longest recurring cycle in its decimal fraction part.

Although I have already provided the correct answer to the problem (983), I still think that the code could have developed even further as I think  the code I wrote could be wrong if the value of d can go over 1000.

I think the code might be wrong because the string limit of the fraction is 20 and what if there is a fraction that has over 20 recurring cycle?

I have tried using format() to increasing the string limit of the fraction, but I realise that the digits after the 20th string are not any of the repeating recurring numbers.

```
import time
import math

timeStart = time.time()

prime_numbers = []

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)+1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def numbers(n):
    for number in range(2, n):
        if is_prime(number):
            prime_numbers.append(number)

def main():
    limit = 1000
    longest_recurring_cycle = 0
    longest_value = 0

    numbers(limit)

    for d in prime_numbers:
        fraction = str(1/d)
        count = 1
        if len(fraction) > 15:
            for index, recurring_cycle in enumerate(fraction[3:10]):
                if recurring_cycle == fraction[2] and recurring_cycle == 
fraction[index + 3 + count]:
                    break
                elif count >= longest_recurring_cycle:
                    longest_recurring_cycle = count
                    longest_value = d
                count += 1
    print(longest_value)
    print(time.time() - timeStart, "seconds")

main()
```

tltr I want to find a way to increase the string limit of the fraction that produces the right number.

Comment: Python strings don't have any limit... maybe you are referring to `float` precision? Use  `Decimal` from the `decimal` module by setting its precision to what you need?

Comment: For working code, consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com as an alternative. If you aren't sure about the math, try https://math.stackexchange.com. Either way, I don't believe that SO is the right forum for your question.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend simulating long division. That is, the digits of 1/7 are 10//7=1, remainder is 10 - 1*7 = 3. Next decimal is 30//7 = 4. Remainder is 2. And so on, until the remainder is equal to 1 again. Then count the length of the cycle.

```
def cycle(denom,num=1):
    digit = None
    decimals=[]
    while digit not in decimals:
        decimals += [digit]
        digit = num * 10 // denom
        remainder = num * 10 - digit * denom
        num = remainder
        print(digit)
    return len(decimals) - decimals.index(digit)
cycle(3)
```

Comment: Why does this give `00` when called with 1000?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code and i got the answer with in a second.I used the simple long division method and considered only remainders.Note that this code doesn't valid when the numerator isn't equal to one.When it is,the function should be develop.

```
def count_repeat(number):
_list = [10]
while ((_list[-1]) % number)*10 not in _list:
    _list.append((_list[-1] % number)*10)

return len(_list)-_list.index((_list[-1] % number)*10)

repeat_lenth = 0
relevent_i = 2
for i in range(2, 1000):
    if count_repeat(i) >= repeat_lenth:
        repeat_lenth = count_repeat(i)
        relevent_i = i
        print(f"{i}-{repeat_lenth}")
print(relevent_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeating_cycle(denom :int, num :int=1)->int:
    '''We will do long division method but we will be tracking the reminder throught the division
    The reason for doing it is sometime the the number in quotient might repeat even though it is part of 
    full cycle. e.g. 1/17 = 0.(0588235294117647) if we were to only look at quotient then 8 is repeted just at the 4th place but our
    actual cycle is of 16 digits.And this is very well known in maths'''

    reminders = []
    rems = None
    while rems not in reminders:
        reminders.append(rems)
        num *= 10
        rems = num % denom
        # reminders.append(rems)
    reminders.pop(0)
    return len(reminders)
```

Well I show someone's answer and that person was keeping track of digits in quotient which might not always get the answer e.g. 1/17 = 0.(058823...) and we see the third 8 is directly repeated but the cycle does not repeat there, infact it repeats after 16 digits, and I that is why it is better to keep track of reminders instead of digits in quotient.

Answer (score 0):

selection method --> right solution is 909

```
 arr = []

for d in range(1, 1000):
    num = 1/d
    if len(str(num)) >= 1:
        arr.append(num)


cnt = 0

for ch in arr:
    cnt += 1
    if len(str(ch)[2:]) == 16:
        if str(ch)[2:10] == str(ch)[10:18]:
            print(f'{cnt}) {ch} --> {len(str(ch)[2:])}')
```